# Likelihood for a model

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

[image]

I am not able to understand what is $x_0$?

Answer (score 1):

The model apparently has some observables.  In this case, you've made an observation and gotten the specific value $x_0$.  Now it's asking about the conditional distribution $f(\theta|x_0)$ given the information in the observation.

Comment: Can you help me with it? I have been trying to do it but have no idea on how to proceed further. My biggest problem is : we don't know it's distribution type so how can we do it?

Comment: The question is really only about normalization.  I guess $L$ is the likelihood function? (That notation was probably defined somewhere else.)  Is the distribution $f(\theta|x_0)$ normalized for any $x_0$?  What about the likelihood?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second question - the answer is no. 
Take for instance $U[0,\theta]$ where $\theta \in [0,1]$, then 
$$
\int_{[0,1]}L(\theta|x_0) d\theta =\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{\theta^n} d\theta,
$$
is not even integrable over $[0,1]$ (Actually, $L$ is basically not defined for $\theta=0$, so you can take $(0,1]$ for better ollustration. In this case, the integral is simply diverge).

The likelihood function is a function defined over the parametric space $\Theta$, i.e., it is not a density w.r.t to $\theta$, hence, integration w.r.t the parameters can equal whatever you want or can be even non-integrable at all.